# PYGTK Application developement help

Tags: programming, pygtk

Can someone give me a basic idea of what is used here to change w indow when different buttons like overview,folders to save,folders to ignore.How multiple windows are embedded within the single window

[image: Image of the application is shown here]

Answer (score 1):

The way it is done in the screenshot that you posted, is via TreeView and ListStore. You will want to create a window with Grid widget inside it, create TreeView widget within it and provide the content via ListStore. After that you can attach some other widget on the right using `grid.attach_next_to(self.some_other_widget, view, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)`. In this case the example is a label, but you probably could attach a Gtk.Box inside with other widgets within.

Note  that this example provides Gtk-3 example. PyGTK is for Gtk-2, which is slowly becoming less and less widespread.

[image]

```py
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Some Title", application=app)
        self.set_default_size(100,100)

        listmodel = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        listmodel.append(['one'])
        listmodel.append(['two'])
        listmodel.append(['three'])

        view = Gtk.TreeView(model=listmodel)

        cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
        col = Gtk.TreeViewColumn("Column Header", cell, text=0)
        view.append_column(col)

        view.get_selection().connect("changed", self.on_changed)

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("")

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        grid.attach(view, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.attach_next_to(self.label, view, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 2, 1)

        self.add(grid)

    def on_changed(self, selection):
        model,iterator = selection.get_selected()
        self.label.set_text("You selected "+model[iterator][0])
        return True


class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

On the other hand, it would probably be simpler and prettier to use [Gtk.Notebook](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkNotebook.html).

See for more info:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pygtk/pygtk_treeview_class.htm
- https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/treeview_simple_liststore.py.html.en

Comment: I used a `GtkNotebook` for this exact usecase in the past. Set `GtkNotebook.set_show_tabs(False)` to hide the tabs on top. When starting new with GTK3 I'd move to `GtkStack` instead: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStack.html